# WPF - Crear combo usando reflexión

Tags: wpf

Necesito crear un *ComboBox* dinámico haciendo uso de reflexión. Tengo creada una pagina de prueba y dos interfaces:

```
public interface IAutoLoader { }

public interface IView<T>
{
    string getDescription();
    T getInstance();
}

public partial class Page1 : Page, IView<Page1>, IAutoLoader
{
    public Page1() { InitializeComponent(); }
    public string getDescription() { return Constants.PAGES_PAGE1; }
    public Page1 getInstance() { return new Page1(); }
}
```

En la clase principal de mi aplicación, extraigo las paginas que heredan de la interfaz `IAutoLoader` con la siguiente linea:

```
var views = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(x => typeof(IAutoLoader).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract).ToList();

List<ComboBoxItem> items = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
views.ForEach(elem => {
    items.Add(new ComboBoxItem()
    {
        Content = elem.ToString()
    });
});
comboConversacion.ItemsSource = items;
```

La duda es, ¿Como puedo crear el ComboBox con esa lista de objetos mostrando los valores devueltos por getDescription() en la propiedad Content?

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Y que exactamente retorna `getDescription();`?

Comment: `Content = elem.getDescription()`?